# Handling Symfony's cache in production

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have a Symfony2 website that I'm testing in production. I went ahead and cleared its cache because I've made and will probably make more modifications, however there is a small problem:

While the cache is being cleared and say, afterwards I want to warm it up, someone that accesses the website rebuilds the cache. That creates a small problem as the cache is being built, but not completely, while half of it gets deleted because the deletion is still in progress.

What happens afterwards is, the cache is built, but only a part of it. Symfony thinks that the cache is built entirely, and runs without trying to build it anymore, but it runs on a half-built cache. The deletion process is a bit long (~15 sec), so in this timeframe nobody must try and create the cache by accessing the website.

Either that, or the cache is completely built, it overwrites the old cache, and the system treats these new files as old ones, deletes part of them and some others remain. Not entirely sure, I'm not sure how to check this.

For instance, one of the errors that I'd get is

```
The directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\med-app\app\app\cache\dev/jms_diextra/metadata" does not exist.
```

If I wouldn't use that bundle I'd get another cache problem from Doctrine. This appears at every website access until I delete the cache again WITHOUT anyone accessing the website. it completely blocks access to the website and makes it non-functional.

Also, what about the warmup? That takes a while, too. What if someone accesses the website while the cache is being warmed up? Doesn't that create a conflict, too?

How to handle this problem? Do I need to close the apache service, clear and warm cache and then restart apache? How is this handled with a website in production?

**EDIT**
Something interesting that I have discovered. The bug occurs when I delete the `cache/prod` folder. If I delete the contents of the folder without deleting the folder itself, it seems the bug does not occur. I wonder why.

Comment: i prefer to remove the cache with 'sudo rm -rf app/cache/*' i think you can decrease the time it will take a lot

Comment: As you are clearing cache manually then refreshing also needs to be done manually, else refer @johnSmith comments to make it automatic refresh at less time or disable it completly.

Comment: Ican't use 'rm' as it is on Windows with xampp.

Comment: Also, what happens if still someone enters the website while this also runs? Wouldn't it also bug it aswell? I don't believe it's purely instant, despite being faster than the other.

Comment: Is the bug resolved if you create the missing directory manually ?

Comment: Why would I create it manually? It creates itself.

Comment: Probably due to permissions. The web server user does not have rights to create a the directory cache/prod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it is good practice to lock the website into maintenance mode if you're performing updates, or clearing the cache for any other reason in the production. Sometimes web hosting services have this option to handle this for you, or there is a [nice bundle](https://github.com/wdalmut/CorleyMaintenanceBundle) for handling maintenance easily from the command line.

This way you can safely delete the cache and be sure no-one visits the page and rebuilds the cache incorrectly.

Comment: There is also a maintenance bundle from lexik, I believe. Would you recommend that one, too? Anyways, does accessing the maintenance pages generated by this bundle try to write or read from the cache? Since that would still not solve the problems.

Comment: I don't have experience with lexik's bundle. `CorleyMaintenanceBundle` has two modes, hard and soft. You are looking for hard lock, that works on apache/nginx level. Soft lock would still access the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Usually if you have to clear the Symfony cache it means you're updating to a new version - so not only are you having to clear the cache, but you're probably having to dump assets and perform other tasks.  In this case what I've done in the past that has worked very well is to treat each production release as its own version n its own folder - so when you install a new version you do it unconnected from the webserver, and then just change your webserver to point to the new version when you are done.  The added benefit is if you mess something up and have to perform a rollback, you just immediately link back to the previous version.

For example, say your Apache config has `DocumentRoot` always points to a specific location:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web
```

You would make that root a symlink to your latest version:

```
/var/www/mysite/web -> /var/www/versions/1.0/web
```

Now say you have version 1.1 of your site to install.  You simply install it to `/var/www/versions/1.1` - put the code there, install your assets, update the cache, etc.  Then simply change the symlink:

```
/var/www/mysite/web -> /var/www/versions/1.1/web
```

Now if the site crashes horribly you can simply point the symlink back.  The benefit here is that there is no downtime to your site and it's easy to rollback if you made a mistake.  To automate this I use a bash script that installs a new version and updates the symlinks with a series of commands connected via `&&` so if one step of the install fails, the whole install fails and you're not stuck between version limbo.

Granted there are probably better ways to do all of the above or ways to automate it further, but the point is if you're changing production you'll want to perform the Symfony installation/setup without letting users interfere with that.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if this can be done with Capifony, too. Doesn't the server become too bloated, though? You have to copy all the `web` images and uploads for every version.

Comment: Yeah that could definitely be a problem.  I mean my sites tend to use virtually no images so the overall footprint is really small, and I don't keep dozens of past versions or anything, just the most recent 2 or 3.  I'm sure Capifony would be a good option...deployment is less of my thing and I try to just get that done as quickly as possible so I can focus on development.